# LaTeX Equation left aligned with smaller fonts size

Tags: math-mode, fonts, formatting

I have the sample below, When I compile and run, each step of the equation is left aligned with smaller fonts.
What I'm trying to achieve is, each step of the equation should appear on a line by itself, normal fonts aligned at `=` sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i^{3} = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{3}\right) +  i^3\\
&=& \frac{k^{2}(k+1)^{2}}{4} + (k+1)^3 
&=& \frac{k^{2}(k+1)^{2} + 4(k+1)^3}{4}\\
&=& \frac{(k+1)^{2}(k^{2} + 4k + 4)}{4}\\
&=& \frac{(k+1)^{2}(k+2)^{2}}{4}\\
\end{align*}

This proves that Eq. (3) holds.  By induction, Eq (1) holds for all positive integers $n$
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Instead of `equation*` use `align*` and use a single `&` _before_ the `=`. Also, please post a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: This code will produce several error messages and typeset a single line that goes beyond the page boundary, but no “smaller font size”.

Comment: @PeterGrill I posted a MWE. After applying `align*` I still get the error

Comment: Use a single `&` and you need the `ams math` package,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the syntax of `eqnarray`, and are forgetting to load `amsmath`; compiling your example produces scores of errors and the output is almost arbitrary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i^{3}
&= \biggl(\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{3}\biggr) +  i^3\\
&= \frac{k^{2}(k+1)^{2}}{4} + (k+1)^3 \\
&= \frac{k^{2}(k+1)^{2} + 4(k+1)^3}{4}\\
&= \frac{(k+1)^{2}(k^{2} + 4k + 4)}{4}\\
&= \frac{(k+1)^{2}(k+2)^{2}}{4}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the trailing `i^3` in the first row should be `(k+1)^3`